# Is it possible to ask Mathematica to stick two plots together to give a continuous plot ? (An example is given)

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a function over a large range of $x$. The problem is that for very large $x$, even increasing PlotPoint to $5\times10^6$ and MaxRecursion 15, it does not give the whole result. But I can get an accurate result for a short domain.

Then, is it possible to ask Mathematica to stick the plots together to give something like a continuous plot over a large range?

For example, if I have

```
P1 = Plot[{0, If[Sin[x \[Pi]] >= 0, 1000]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[White, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[-1], 
     Thickness[0]], 
    Directive[Red, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1000], Thickness[.04]]}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 6, AspectRatio -> 1/40, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, Ticks -> {{0, 5, 10}, {0, 0}}]
P2 = Plot[{0, If[Cos[x \[Pi]] >= 0, 1000]}, {x, 10, 20}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[White, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[-1], 
     Thickness[0]], 
    Directive[Blue, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1000], Thickness[.04]]}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/40, Axes -> {True, False}, 
  Ticks -> {{10, 15, 20}, {0, 0}}]
```

which the result is this

[image]

then, how to ask Mathematica to stick them as a continuous plot and gives something like this

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Show[P1, P2, PlotRange -> All, Ticks -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 That was an easy one :-)